integrals with residue method
I am trying to calculate the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(3\theta)}{5-4\cos(\theta)}d\theta
$$
The result should be $\frac{\pi}{12}$, but for the function
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{z^6+1}{z^3(z-1/2)(z-2)}
$$
I obtain the residues $Res_{z=0}(f)=-\frac{21}{8}i$ and $Res_{z=1/2}(f)=\frac{65}{24}i$. Thus, I obtain that the integral above is equal to:
$$
2\pi i \left(\frac{65}{24}-\frac{21}{8}\right)i=-\frac{\pi}{6}\neq \frac{\pi}{12}
$$
I verified the residues several times with Wolfram Alpha, so what is wrong?
Note: the function $f(z)$ comes from the fact that $\cos(3\theta)=\frac{e^{i3\theta}+e^{-i3\theta}}{2}$ and $\cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$, so if I choose
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\frac{\frac{z^3+\frac{1}{z^3}}{2}}{5-4(\frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2})}\cdot \frac{1}{iz}
\end{equation*}
I obtain that:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{S^1}f(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(3\theta)}{5-4\cos(\theta)}d\theta
\end{equation*}

This is far from a complete and clear question. Edit your post to show where $f(z)$ came from. Did you remember that $d\theta = -i\frac{dz}z$?

I edited the post now

The algebra does not check.

Your thought process is fine only the change is that $\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\frac{\frac{z^3+\frac{1}{z^3}}{2}}{5-4(\frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2})}\cdot \frac{1}{iz}=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{z^6+1}{-z^3(2z-1)(z-2)}
\end{equation*}$ as you have done a minor calculation error. Therefore the residue of $f(z)$ will be at $z=0$ will be $\frac{21}{16}i$ and at $z=1/2$ it will be $\frac{-65}{48}i$.
This will give the answer as $2\pi i$$\frac{-1}{24}i$ which will give answer as $\frac{ π}{12} $

But I have already considered that $\frac{1}{2i}$ in the calculations of residues, so why should I have to divide for $2i$ at the end?

@Steppenwolf I have edited as I was a bit wrong
